# Fail on setting attribute for canvas from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, height, width

I have to set the attributes 'width' and 'height' for a canvas element, depending on the available screen resolution. Setting them statically from html works (ex. `<canvas id="canv" width="1600" ...` ). From Javascript I can't do it. I've googled and searched in SO but I didn't find anything that works. I am using JQuery and I've tried unsuccessfully the following (the same for height attribute)

```
$('#canv').setAttribute('width',screen.availWidth);
$('#canv').attr('width',screen.availWidth);
$('#canv').data('width',screen.availWidth);
$('#canv').width = screen.availWidth;
$('#canv').css('width',screen.availWidth);
```

I did the same putting `var cv = $('#canv')[0].getContext("2d");` and changing `$('#canv')` with `cv` but with no result.

bb

Comment: Are you trying to maximize it to the **browser** viewable area, or to the user's **screen** size?

Comment: I'm trying to maximize it to the browser viewable area..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed the code on [jsfiddle.net/pUcjV/2](http://jsfiddle.net/pUcjV/2) to

```
$('#canv').attr("width", screen.availWidth);    
$('#canv').attr("height", screen.availHeight);  
circlesBG (cv, col, screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
```

from

```
circlesBG (cv, col, screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
$('#canv').width(screen.availWidth);    
$('#canv').height(screen.availHeight);
```

This produced stars over the whole canvas. Is this the desired result?
I'm using Chrome 5.0.375.99.

Comment: It works :) now I see if it works in the original page too, but I think this solves everything :) thanks so much .. I will try to rate these answers even if I've less than 15 of reputation :D

Comment: It works definitely.. Weird thing: if you compare the canvas made with the attributes in html http://jsfiddle.net/pUcjV/7/ to the last canvas we made with the attributes inserted by js http://jsfiddle.net/pUcjV/8/ the first one has antialiasing, the last one hasn't :\

Comment: Got the anti-aliasing working. Just retrieved the context after the size change - http://jsfiddle.net/pUcjV/11/. This was again with Chrome 5.0.375.99.

Comment: thanks.. I just got it working by inserting the script directly in the html http://jsfiddle.net/7eCxx/1 but yours is a cleaner solution :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, but I'm not sure if the *screen* size is what you're after:

```
$('#canv').width(screen.availWidth);​
```

[You can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/pUcjV/)

Comment: This one half solved it, thanks; as you can see in the http://jsfiddle.net/pUcjV/2/ demo, now the area has wanted dimensions.. but I can't draw canvas pixel per pixel.. it just draws the background in the standard dimensions and then maximizes it..

Comment: Moreover consider I'm using canvas with HTML 5.. just thinking.. maybe it requires attributes on the main source..